# Java : object of a class as instance variable in same class

Tags: java, member-variables

Being a beginner, I have a conceptual doubt. What is the use of a class type object as member/instance variable in the same class?
Something like this :

```
class MyClass {

static MyClass ref;
String[] arguments;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ref = new MyClass();
    ref.func(args);
}

public void func(String[] args) {
    ref.arguments = args;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RyanJ other way around: you can't access non-static from static code.

Answer (score 4):

This is used in the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

```
class MyClass {
    private static final MyClass INSTANCE = new MyClass();
    private MyClass() {}
    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    // instance methods omitted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general case of having a class have a member/attribute that is of the same class is often used.  One example is for implementing [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Comment: No. OP has a static field, not an instance.

Comment: I thought the 'conceptual' problem meant the general construct, not specifically referencing the static'ness of the field.

Comment: A linked list needs an instance field (ie non static) to hold a reference to the next node.

Answer (score 0):

The only use that I can see is to invoke any instance methods of the same class from the static methods with out re-creating the object again and again. Something like as follows...

```
public class MyClass {

static MyClass ref;
String[] arguments;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ref = new MyClass();
    func1();
    func2();
}

public static void func1() {
    ref.func();
}

public static void func2() {
    ref.func();
}

public void func() {
    System.out.println("Invoking instance method func");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you mean self-referential classes in general, they are very useful for any structure where an instant of that class needs to point to neighboring instant(s) in that structure, as in graphs (like trees), linked lists, etc. As for the specific example where a static field of the same type as the enclosing class is present, this may be used in design patterns like the singleton pattern.